# Understanding Truffle Migration

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, truffle-migration

I'm building my dApp by modifying the pet-shop example, however, I got stuck at the migration step. `1_initial_migration.js` runs successfully but `2_deploy_contracts.js` gives me the following error despite the fact I modified it accordingly.

I've read all the [Migration Documentation](https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/beta/getting_started/migrations/) and gone through a number of related post but I'm still having a hard time understanding how it relates to my project.

> ... 0x48c02fda96b9e71d1b219e4b09876181027c60aa2589c9ccd7f46f2970e4f34b
>   Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful
>   transactions manually. Error: VM Exception while processing
>   transaction: invalid opcode
>       at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\charles.fried\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:43303:16)
>       at C:\Users\charles.fried\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:331156:36
>       at C:\Users\charles.fried\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:175492:11
>       at C:\Users\charles.fried\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:314196:9
>       at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\charles.fried\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:329855:7)
>       at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\charles.fried\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:70159:18)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\charles.fried\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:70449:12)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\charles.fried\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:70604:12)
>       at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\charles.fried\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:70564:24)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)

2_deploy_contracts.js:

```
var Plant = artifacts.require("Plant");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Plant);
};
```

Plant.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Plant {

    address public creator;

    // initial Variables
    uint public number_of_leaves;
    uint public remaining_leaves = 0; // has to start on 1 otherwise it cancels price calculation
    uint public initial_coins;
    uint public total_supply;
    uint public finney_balance; // 1 Ether is 1,000 finney - see this converter -> https://converter.murkin.me/
    uint public plant_price = 60; // Price is in Finney $20 if approx 60 Finney
    uint public number_of_plants;

    // Modififer to check if there's enough money for a new plant without wasting gas
    modifier onlyIfEnoughMoney() {
        require(finney_balance > plant_price); 
        _;
    }

    // only_creator can update price
    modifier onlyCreator() {
        require(msg.sender == creator);
        _;
    }

    // you need to send some money to initialise the contract
    modifier enoughToInitialise() {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        _;
    }

    function Plant(uint _number_of_leaves, uint _initial_coins) public payable enoughToInitialise {
        number_of_leaves = _number_of_leaves;
        remaining_leaves = number_of_leaves;
        initial_coins = _initial_coins;
        total_supply = initial_coins;
        finney_balance = msg.value/1000000000000000;
        creator = msg.sender;
        number_of_plants ++;
        depositedFunds(msg.value, finney_balance);
    }

    function buy_new_plant() private onlyIfEnoughMoney {

        uint number_plants_to_buy = finney_balance / plant_price;

        total_supply += (initial_coins*number_plants_to_buy);
        finney_balance -= (plant_price*number_plants_to_buy);
        number_of_plants += number_plants_to_buy; 
        plantWasPurchased(finney_balance, total_supply, number_of_plants);
    }

    function () payable public {
        finney_balance += msg.value/1000000000000000;
        buy_new_plant();
        depositedFunds(msg.value, finney_balance);
    }

    function terminate() private onlyCreator{
        selfdestruct(creator);
    }

    function leafPicked(uint numPicked) public onlyCreator returns (uint){
        require(numPicked < remaining_leaves);
        remaining_leaves -= numPicked;
        leafWasPicked(remaining_leaves, numPicked);
    }

    event leafWasPicked(uint leavesLeft, uint numberTaken);
    event plantWasPurchased(uint newBalance, uint newTotalSupply, uint newPlantNumber); // Event
    event depositedFunds(uint amount, uint newBalance); // Event

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the deployer call, you need to pass in the arguments of the Plant constructor.
Otherwise, the constructor fails because the arguments are undefined.

```
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  deployer.deploy(Plant, <someNumberOfLeaves>, <someInitialCoin>, { from: accounts[0], value: 1e18 );
};
```

This is mentioned in this section: [Deployer API](https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/beta/getting_started/migrations/#deployer-api)

Comment: Much appreciated, the initialisation function is also payable and requires some ether to be sent. How should I do this?

Comment: You can specify the value to send when deploying the contract in the parameters object following the arguments.  See my revised answer.  Note I also added parameters to the function (network & accounts) so you can specify which account the value is coming from

Comment: I can see `accounts` being used but not `network`, could briefly explain its role?

Comment: networks is the object key / string (such as "development", "testnet", "mainnet") from your truffle.js config file of the network that deployer is deploying to (http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations#network-considerations).  I included that there because the function argument syntax requires that there's a networks parameter before accounts (http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations#available-accounts)